# path alias or real path has higher priority?

Tags: views, path-aliases

By default in Drupal , a views create to show all term , its Url is `taxonomy/%` (%=termid),I has special vocab that I want set another views with my fields and style , I set path alias to that vocab  to `cast/term/[term:tid]`  and  I create a optional views ,views url path is `cast/term/%` , (and get `%` with contextual filter, it is not important because every thing is views is ok) , my problem is where access (as example)  `cast/term/21` , it show me the result of `taxonomy/%` views result not my views.
I think this happen because Drupal default views work with Url and I work with alias of that Url and work with raw Url has higher priority,I want to know what is the exact reason of this job, and how can achieve my job?
(I have A idea that work with hook_menu_alter or set menu with hook_menu in my custom module and in call back of it call my views)
appreciate any help and idea

Comment: Did you clear your Drupal cache?  If you use drush, try `drush cc menu` or `drush cc all`

Comment: @Citricguy Yes I did,